# Hide an element when a specific string is present in the url

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide a button when the string "wholesale' is present in the url. I've tried a few variations of the following code but it just won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (/wholesale/.test(window.location.href)) {
       document.getElementsByClassName('variations_button')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can use indexOf if test is now working.

Comment: Works for me. Can you give us a sample URL that you are using?

Comment: Sure. http://www.stutzman.asia/products/wholesale/wholesale_bags/wholesale_change_purses/lisu-change-purse-w-belt-loop/ You have to select a color for the button to appear. It's the 'Add to Cart" button I need to hide.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName('variations_button')[0].style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.

```
 var patt = new RegExp("wholesale");
    if (patt.test(window.location.href)) {
          $('.variations_button').hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong with the select element by class name code

it should be like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('variations_button')[0].style.display='none'
```

Note:

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements with the same class name. So `document.getElementsByClassName('variations_button')[0]` will return the first element with the class name `variations_button`.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with `getElementByClassName`, it should be `getElementsByClassName` and will return a `HTMLCollection` (Array like object) not an element. You should probably also use jQuery if that is already loaded on the page. jQuery is an array like object of HTMLElements that will give you methods that will run over the entire collection.

edit:
here is a working example, click 'Run code snippet' to see the result. I had to change the regex to match what was in the snippet, but you should get the idea.

```js
console.log( 'is jQuery installed on the page', typeof $ !== void 0 );
$(function () {
  console.log( 'href', window.location.href );
  if (/stacksnippets/.test(window.location.href)) {
    console.log('regex found in href');
    $('.variations_button').css('background', '#3cf');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<button class="variations_button">variations button</button>
```

Comment: Good catch. How do I use JQuery? The code above isn't working with the <script type="text/javascript"> tag. Nor are any of the other solutions working, unfortunately.

Comment: you need to include jQuery on your page. The first line of your code is specifically for jQuery. it is an event listener for when the DOM is ready to be manipulated. go into your console and type in `$.fn.jquery` to find out the version number you are using. if you don't have it installed you can get it from code.jquery.com and use script tags to include it in your page

Comment: Ok, I have jQuery installed and it is being used on the page. (ver=1.11.3) But the code is still not working. I changed variations_button to other elements like the logo and still nothing.